# as3 air for android Scrolling by GESTURE_SWIPE

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm trying to simulate scrolling by GESTURE_SWIPE event but the only useful data in this event is  offsetY,offsetX but the handler function dosent receives any data about how fast the user swipes or how far or any other data to calculate it .
the page contain several movie clips that should be able to scroll smoothly.
how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Greensock has a plugin called ThrowProps which provides the same  behaviour as your would get in a native menu.

https://greensock.com/throwprops-as